# error parsing called workflow in github . workflow was not found

Tags: github, github-actions, pulumi

Trying to use pulumi preview with Github actions. The workflow file is giving me the below error.

> Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/pull_request.yml#L12

> error parsing called workflow "peopleticker/ccc/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml@master": workflow was not found.

I'm using the workflow file below kindly check:

```
name: Call a reusable workflow

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: peopleticker/ccc/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml@master
```

Comment: In which repository is this workflow? Are you sure the file `pull_request.yml` exists in the repository `ccc`? If the repository `ccc` is private, then you can't reference it. You can only reference public reusable workflows or within an org.

Comment: It is within an org. Not able to figure out where I am actually going wrong

Answer (score 11):

According to GitHub document:
[doc](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#managing-access-for-a-private-repository-in-an-organization)

You can visit repository Setting -> Actions -> Access: Choose "Accessible from repositories in the organization"

Answer (score 1):

You can use private repo workflows but you have to give access on org level.
Github give access that.
Related documentaion: [github-doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/sharing-workflows-secrets-and-runners-with-your-organization)
Example Video Explanation: [video-expl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qS9UbbkGa4)

Answer (score 0):

> Actions and reusable workflows in your private repositories can be shared with other private repositories owned by the same user or organization.

> **Managing access for a private repository in an organization**
>
> 1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the private repository.
> 2. Under your repository name, click **Settings**.
> 3. In the left sidebar, click **Actions**, then click **General**.
> 4. Under **Access**, choose one of the access settings:
>
>    - **Not accessible** - Workflows in other repositories cannot access this repository.
>    - **Accessible from repositories in the 'ORGANIZATION NAME'** organization - Workflows in other repositories that are part of the 'ORGANIZATION NAME' organization can access the actions and reusable workflows in this repository. Access is allowed only from private repositories.
> 5. Click *Save* to apply the settings.

[source](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository)

---

**Outdated, valid at the time the question was asked:**

You can't use reusable workflows from other private repositories.

> Reusable workflows stored within a private repository can only be used by workflows within the same repository.

[source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)

Answer (score 0):

If the repository that hosts the reusable workflow is a fork of another repository, make sure to enable GitHub Actions in the Actions tab of the repository